# How to get the process id which uses the administrative directory(/var/lib/dpkg)?

Tags: dpkg, process

Sometimes when I try to install something using `sudo apt-get install` it shows results looks like ---

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Now, I want to know the process(name , id) which is using it. If the process is no more needed I can kill it.

How can I know the process id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "fuser" to get the pid of the pocess to kill:

```
sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

you can use switch "-k" with fuser to kill the processes hanging on /var/lib/dpkg/lock

Comment: It might not be the best idea to just kill the process. If `dpkg` is running, it is most likely busy manipulating the package database or installing/updating/removing some packages. Interrupting this might get you into trouble. Better just check what process is owning the lock and then wait a few minutes and check again, giving it a chance to exit normally.

Comment: you right, Byte Commander. but this was not the question.

Comment: Yes, but an additional warning is always a good idea. Especially as not only the OP will read your answer but everybody who comes by and finds this question.